# How to change the Amaon Linux test page on AWS Instance?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, scp

I'm pretty new to the AWS. I have created my AWS Instance and installed httpd service on it. Now, when I start httpd and open that webpage, I can see that it is running perfectly. I want to change that webpage to something else which is saved as index.html on my local machine in the documents folder. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to connect via ssh, all my key pairs are having read-only permissions. (I used chmod 400)

How can this be done?

Comment: In short you upload the new file using sftp (which is file transfer over ssh and is built into most modern OS's) and replace the existing index.html file. I don't know where Ubuntu puts that file, but it can often be in /var/www . You'd be best picking up a tutorial or course on AWS and another on Apache.